# yagmail installation win32ctypes matching distribution not found error

Tags: python-3.x, yagmail

yagmail was working for me, this is the first time ive tried it since I upgraded to python 3.5, and it doesnt work. I uninstalled yagmail and tried to pip install it again but it showed me this error on no matching distribution found for win32ctypes?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyzIF.jpg

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a keyring issue. Probably they need to support windows for Python3.5

You could try to see if their most recent version on git works:

```
pip uninstall keyring
pip install git+https://github.com/jaraco/keyring.git
pip install yagmail
```

Let me know, and feel free to [open a ticket on github](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail) as well.

Not sure if that would work: there are no issues for Python 3.5 on OS' other than Windows.

Comment: It worked! Strange, I tried re-installing keyring but to no avail. I guess the git version worked. Thank you so much! :)